# The words "not working" always trigger the default intent in Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have been working with Google Dialogflow to create a Google Assistant experience.

My GA Action is to Raise Support tickets and those tickets are raised in our system via API.
[image: Welcome Intent]

We ask the user to describe the Issue they are facing, We have used a fallback Intent to capture the Issue/Ticket Description(Since the reply can be any free text, is this the best way to capture free text?).

[image: Default fallback Intent]

Once the user gives a description, A webhook is called and the results are sent to our backend to capture.

We have noticed that when the user uses the words "not working" as a part of the issue description, it always calls the welcome intent, instead of going to the follow up Intent. If the user describes the Issue without using those words, it works fine. Below are 2 different responses.

[image: Response with the words not working]

[image: Reponse without the words not working]

I personally feel that this is a bug in GA, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55556992/edit) your question to include screen shots of your Intents, particularly the Intents that you think should be triggered as well as the "default intent"? It is difficult to diagnose what is going on without further information. [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: I have added it and given more details, not sure what screenshots should i post

Comment: Are you using Contexts in any of your Intents? A full screen shot of your Welcome Intent and your Fallback Intent are most helpful, although if you have other Intents, particularly any that are triggered before this point in the conversation, those might be helpful as well. Why do you think it is your Welcome Intent being triggered? Showing this evidence is useful. If you're using the simulator, the text of the Request and Response tabs can help as well. See the article linked to above for other things that may help.

Comment: To be clear - screen shots of the Intents in the Dialogflow UI.

Comment: Have you tried training the agent in the dialogflow? You can basically train the agent so that it triggers the right intent in the future.

Comment: Check what intent and action is detected (check it on the right [my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppih9.png)), there you can check the utterances.

Comment: I have edited and added as much info as possible, I hope that helps. Also is fallback intent the best way to get "free text"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing some things wrong. I don't have enough information to understand 100% what you are doing, but I will try to give you some general advice:

A fallback intent is used to 'fall back' to this intent when a user asks something that is nowhere provided in one of your other intents. That's why your fallback intent has the 'input.unknown' set as action. It will be triggered when the user gives some input that is unknown for your application. F.e. I don't think your '(Pazo) Support Action' will provide an answer if the user asks to book a plane to Iceland, so that's when your fallback intent comes in to give an answer such as 'Sorry, I can't answer that question. Pazo is here to give you support in... What can I do for you?'

Your user can either register a complaint or raise a support ticket if I'm getting this right? I recommend you to make two seperate intents. One to handle the complaints and one to handle the support tickets.

Before developing advanced actions with a seperate webhook and a lot of logic with calling an API etc., I recommend to go through the documentation of Actions on Google:
https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant